# Difference between big-O notation and theta notation, why (theta) Ө-notation is suitable to insertion sort to describe its worst case running time?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, math, time-complexity

**`We use Ө-notation to write worst case running time of insertion sort. But I’m not able to relate properties of Ө-notation with insertion sort, why Ө-notation is suitable to insertion sort. How does the insertion sort function f(n), lies between the c1*n^2 and c2*n^2 for all n>=n0.`**

Running time of insertion sort as Ө(n^2) implies that it has upper bound O(n^2) and lower bound Ω(n^2). I’m confuse in whether insertion sort lower bound is Ω(n^2) or Ω(n).

[image]

Comment: I voted to close this as "not a real question", a condition that SE summarizes as "It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form."  Specifically, the second paragraph is full of misinformation and the whole thing is a peeve instead of a question.

Comment: My question is," Why do we use Ө-notation for insertion sort ?" i suppose this can be answered. i write my all doubts in the question. i guess these doubts makes question doubtful.

Comment: Consider moving your edit to a new answer and accept it (yes, you can answer your own question and accept it). That way, you may both get up-votes and mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The use of Ө-notation :**

---

If any function have same both upper bound and lower bound,  we can use Ө-notation to describe its time complexity.Both its upper bound and lower bound can be specified with single notation. It simply tells more about the characteristic of the function.

**Example ,**

```
suppose we have a function , 
                  f(n) = 4logn + loglogn  
             we can write this function as 
                  f(n) = Ө(logn)
             Because its upper bound and lower bound
are O(logn) and  Ω(logn) repectively, which are same 
so it is legal to write this function as , 
                  f(n)=  Ө(logn)
```

Proof:

```
     **Finding upper bound :**

 f(n) = 4logn+loglogn


    For all sufficience value of n>=2

        4logn <= 4 logn   
        loglogn <= logn 

    Thus , 

     f(n) = 4logn+loglogn <= 4logn+logn
                          <= 5logn
                           = O(logn)       // where c1 can be 5 and n0 =2
**Finding lower bound :**

   f(n) = 4logn+loglogn

   For all sufficience value of n>=2

      f(n) = 4logn+loglogn >= logn
    Thus,              f(n) =  Ω(logn)   // where c2 can be 1 and n0=2


  so , 
                        f(n) = Ɵ(logn)
```

[image]

---

**Similarly, in the case of insertion sort:**

---

```
If running time of insertion sort is described by simple function f(n).
In particular , if f(n) = 2n^2+n+1 then 

Finding upper bound:
      for all sufficient large value of n>=1
                         2n^2<=2n^2   ------------------- (1)
                           n <=n^2    --------------------(2)
                           1 <=n^2    --------------------(3)
        adding eq 1,2 and 3, we get.
                     2n^2+n+1<= 2n^2+n^2+n^2
        that is 
                         f(n)<= 4n^2
                         f(n) = O(n^2)  where c=4 and n0=1 

Finding lower bound:
       for all sufficient large value of n>=1
                           2n^2+n^2+1 >= 2n^2
         that is , 
                                f(n) >= 2n^2
                                f(n) = Ω(n^2) where c=2 and n0=1     
      because upper bound and lower bound are same,
                                f(n) = Ө(n^2)


   if f(n)= 2n^2+n+1 then, c1*g(n) and c2*g(n) are presented by diagram:
```

[image]

**In worst case, insertion sort upper bound and lower bound are O(n^2) and Ω(n^2), therefore in worst case it is legal to write the running of insertion sort as Ө(n^2))**

**In best case, it would be Ө(n).**

Answer (score 1):

The best case running time of insertion time is Ө(n) and worst case is Ө(n^2) to be precise. So the running time of insertion sort is O(n^2) not Ө(n^2). O(n^2)  means that the running time of the algorithm should be less than or equal to n^2, where as Ө(n^2) means it should be exactly equal to n^2.

The worst case running time will never be less than Ө(n^2). We use Ө(n^2) because it is more accurate.

Comment: if f(n) belong to Ө(g(n)) we write it as f(n)= Ө(g(n)), then f(n) must satisfies the properties. And properties state that there exits constants c1, c2 and n0 such that 0<=c1*g(n)<=f(n)<=c2*g(n) For all n>n0, it doesn’t imply that f(n) should be exactly equal to c1*g(n) or c2*g(n)

Answer (score 1):

Insertion Sort Time "Computational" Complexity: O(n^2), Ω(n)

```
O(SUM{1..n}) = O(1/2 n(n+1)) = O(1/2 n^2 + 1/2 n)) ~ O(n^2)

Ө(SUM{1..(n/2)}) = Ө(1/8 n(n+2)) = Ө(1/8 n^2 + 1/4 n) ~ Ө(n^2)
```

Here is a paper that shows that Gapped Insertion Sort is O(n log n), an optimal version of insertion sort: [Gapped Insertion Sort](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.9.3665)

But if you are looking for faster sorting algorithm, there's [Counting Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) which has Time: O(3n) at its worst case when k=n (all symbols are unique), Space: O(n)

Comment: He is not looking for additional algorithms. OP's question is clear and related to big Ө notation, so please keep it on-topic

Comment: @Alexander I answered his question, additional information are additional and they're related to the topic ..